# Unable to update an existing excel file with values for a certain cell in C#

Tags: c#, excel, cell

I developed a program that tries to update certain cells of an existing excel sheet. When I try to set the values of certain cells, I can't find my changes applied to the saved excel sheet.
Here is the code of the method that updates the excel sheet cells with certain values:

```
public static string filePath = @"D:\Egyption Consulate\StatisticalTemplate.xlsx";
        public void UpdateExcelTmplate(Dictionary<int,int> source, string ExcelHeader)
        {
            Application xlApp = new Application();
            Workbook xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(filePath, 0, false, 5, "", "", false,
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "", true, false, 0, true, false, false);
            Worksheet xlWorkSheet = (Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
            Range xlRange = xlWorkSheet.UsedRange;

            xlWorkSheet.Cells[3, 12] = source[0];
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[4, 12] = source[1];
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[5, 12] = source[0] + source[1];

            xlApp.DisplayAlerts = false;
            xlWorkBook.SaveAs(filePath, XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook,
                Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange,
                XlSaveConflictResolution.xlLocalSessionChanges, Missing.Value, Missing.Value,
                Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
            xlWorkBook.Close();
            xlApp.Quit();

            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkSheet);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkBook);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlApp);

            MessageBox.Show("Done");
        }
```

I checked all posts on stackoverflow and they are using the same way i'm using but my issue that cells' values are not updated. Does anyone know what is the reason behind that issue?

Comment: The only change I made to the posted code was… `Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();` and made Excel visible, other than that the code works as expected in my tests. Is there something else going on?  Are you sure your dictionary has values?

Comment: you are saying that code works as expected. Did you try to update the cells and they was updated successfully? Yes the dictionary has values. My only issue is that cells are not updated and I don't know why. Also did you open the existing excel file and made it visible while you update it? How did you do that?

Comment: Yes, the code worked as expected with new values and updated values. Are you sure you are looking at the right Excel file? The name of the original file ends in the word “Template”, however is has an `xlsx` extension, so I will assume the file is not a template. I would double check and make sure you are checking the right file… or easier… add the line… `xlApp.Visible` and step through the code when it writes the values to the worksheet.

Comment: Yes the name is template but it's a regular .xlsx file. I will try to what you advised and provide you with feedback.

Comment: I tried xlApp.Visible and the file is opened and I confirm it is the file that I specified in my code. The issue is that it does not reflect my changes. Shall I add any line of code to submit changes or apply changes? or what do you recommend?

Answer (score 0):

I know the issue now. There was a lock on the excel file in addition to that I used incorrect index of excel row and column.